# SpringData MongoDB - convert generic sub-document fields

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In the following case, when I save *CharFoo* objects and then do a *find*, the generic field **abstractFooField** is converted back to a Character, but **bar.field** from the sub-document is converted to a String and not to a Character.
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this not supported by Spring Data MongoDB?

P.S: I'm using spring-data-mongodb 1.6.0.RC1 and spring-data-commons 1.9.0.RC1

```
@Document(collection = "foo")
public abstract class AbstractFoo<T> {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private T abstractFooField;
    private AbstractBar<T> bar;

    public AbstractFoo() {}

    public AbstractFoo(T abstractFooField, AbstractBar<T> bar) {
        this.abstractFooField = abstractFooField;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}


public class CharFoo extends AbstractFoo<Character> {

    public CharFoo() {}

    public CharFoo(Character abstractFooField,
            AbstractBar<Character> bar) {
        super(abstractFooField, bar);
    }
}

@Document
public class AbstractBar<T> {
    public AbstractBar() {}
}

public class Bar<T> extends AbstractBar<T> {

    private T field;

    public Bar(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void givenGenericEntities_whenFindOne_thenReturnCorrectTypes() {
    // GIVEN
    Bar<Character> charBar = new Bar<>('A');
    CharFoo charFoo = new CharFoo('B', charBar);
    fooRepository.save(charFoo);

    // WHEN
    CharFoo dbCharFoo = charFooRepository.findOne(charFoo.getId());

    // THEN
    assertEquals("Field class should match", Character.class, dbCharFoo.getAbstractFooField().getClass());
    assertEquals("Field class from sub-class should match", Character.class, ((Bar) dbCharFoo.getBar()).getField()
            .getClass());
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Field class from sub-class should match 
Expected :class java.lang.Character
Actual   :class java.lang.String
```

MongoDB document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54db485a06e70e8444a15291"),
    "_class" : "com.test.model.CharFoo",
    "abstractFooField" : "B",
    "bar" : {
        "_class" : "com.test.model.Bar",
        "field" : "A"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a test case handy showing what you're trying to achieve and what exactly you're trying to achieve? Some exceptions or failed test assertions that you get?

Comment: @OliverGierke Sorry for the way too long delay. I added a failing unit test. Hope it helps to better describe my problem...

Comment: As I recently encountered this "issue" again, I added the following bug [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1312)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by [DATAMONGO-1312](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1312) in spring-data-mongodb 1.8.1

Comment: Hi @MirceaG. I'm having the same issue while using spring boot version 1.5.7 which uses version spring-data-mongodb 1.10.7. Have you tried the fix that was implemented in the version you mentioned above? (1.8.1)